# Problem with running VBA macro from Python

Tags: python-3.x, vba

[image: Error]

I am trying to run a VBA script (the script refers to a button, CommandButton1_Click ()), from a Python script. But all the time he writes an error that the macro cannot be found. I tried different spellings of names, put the macro as Public Sub. The CommandButton1_Click () macro itself calls the main macro. It is what, in fact, is needed, but it is launched only through CommandButton1_Click (). It seems to me that the point is in the passed argument, but how to pass it correctly? ActiveSheet.Name not working

Python:

```
if os.path.exists(r'./Результат/Отчет_Собираемость — копия.xlsm'):
    excel_macro = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
    excel_path = os.path.expanduser(r'\\guo.local\DFSFILES\MSK\HOME\dobychin.ia\Desktop\report collection\1 вариант(Загрузка данных - Python, формирование отчета -VBA)\Результат/Отчет_Собираемость — копия.xlsm')
    workbook = excel_macro.Workbooks.Open(Filename=excel_path, ReadOnly =1)
    param = "ActiveSheet.Name"
    # excel_macro.Application.Run("Отчет_Собираемость.xlsm!Лист3 (ОТЧЕТ_день).CommandButton1_Click()")
    excel_macro.Application.Run("CommandButton1_Click")
    workbook.Save()
    excel_macro.Application.Quit()
    del excel_macro
```

VBA:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call main(ActiveSheet.Name)
MsgBox ("Готово!")
End Sub
```

VBA:

```
Sub main(ws_name)
Call optimize
Call dell_sheets

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws_name)
ws.CommandButton1.Visible = False
ws.SpinButton1.Visible = False
Set dws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("!Периоды")
i = 1
Do While dws.Cells(i, 3) <> ""
    mc = dws.Cells(i, 3)
    ws.Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    Set aws = ActiveSheet
    aws.Cells(3, 2) = mc
    Application.Calculate
    aws.UsedRange.Value = aws.UsedRange.Value
    aws.Name = mc
    i = i + 1
Loop
ws.Activate
ws.CommandButton1.Visible = True
ws.SpinButton1.Visible = True
Call unoptimize

End Sub
```

Comment: You probably need the sheet code module name (assuming that click handler is in a worksheet module) - eg. `excel_macro.Application.Run("Sheet1.CommandButton1_Click")`  Also using `Activesheet.Name` probably works fine when clicking that button manually, since for the user to click the button the sheet must be active, but in an automation setting there's no guarantee which sheet is active...

Comment: Good guide here:  https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm